# How do I disable Default Browser Shortcuts in Flutter Web?

Tags: javascript, html, flutter, flutter-web

### Problem

If I implement shortcuts for <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> in my Flutter web app, the **browser** will still *zoom by default*. I want to prevent the browser from doing so when I override the shorcuts.

### Use case

When I have my custom shortcut behavior (using [`Shortcuts`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Shortcuts-class.html) e.g.), I do not want the browser to still respond to it, but there is no way to prevent the default action in Flutter itself.

Another example is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, which creates a bookmark in Firefox. I want to use the shortcut for duplication in my Flutter web app.

---

How do I prevent the defaults?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prevent the default browser actions directly in HTML using JS. Flutter has not implemented a way to trigger this using the framework (and I doubt they will because it is web-specific).

---

If you wanted to, you could also do this using Dart code instead, using the [`dart:html`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.2/dart-html/dart-html-library.html) library. However, it is most convenient to directly include the following **JavaScript** code in the `index.html` of your Flutter web app (in the `<body>` tag):

```html
<script>
  // This prevents default browser actions on key combinations.
  // See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67039463/6509751.
  window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (event.target == document.body) {
      // Prevents going back to the previous tab.
      if (event.key == 'Backspace') {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  
    if (event.metaKey || event.ctrlKey) {
      switch (event.key) {
        case '=': // Prevent zooming in.
        case '-': // Prevent zooming out.
        case 'd': // Prevent bookmark on Firefox e.g.
        case 'g': // Prevent open find on Firefox e.g.
        case 'z': // Prevent restoring tab on Safari.
          event.preventDefault();
          break;
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

As you can see, I added a few examples, like <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> et al. inspired by Rive.

Additionally, I added a snippet that prevents going back to the previous tab on pressing backspace. The use case for this is if you want to use backspace as a shortcut for deletion *outside of text input*.

Comment: should be '+' instead of '=' for zooming in, cant make an edit since the change is to small

Comment: @omnesia `=` is correct - this is intentional. This is the key that is triggered when zooming in because `+` is on the same physical key, just with a modifier.

Comment: this does not work for international keyboards like e.g. qwertz.
For german keyboards, '+' is modified to '*'

Comment: If you're suppressing ctrl-g, wouldn't you also want to also suppress ctrl-f?